# How to get the last taken picture

Tags: c#, winforms, wia

can some tell me how to get a preview image of the last taken picture from my camera with WIA?

This is all you need to take a picture:

```
//select device
WIA.CommonDialog dialog = new WIA.CommonDialog();
WIA.Device camera = dialog.ShowSelectDevice(WIA.WiaDeviceType.CameraDeviceType, false, true);

//take picture 
camera.ExecuteCommand("{AF933CAC-ACAD-11D2-A093-00C04F72DC3C}");
```

with this I can get all camera properties, but there is no last picture info:

```
string p = "";
foreach (Property p in camera.Properties)
{
    p += p.Name + ":\t" + p.get_Value() + "\n";
}
MessageBox.Show(p);
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# WIA:" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Please show some source code... what have you tried ? what is not working ?

Comment: Be aware, not all cams support WIA.  Might need to look at DirectShow unless you're targeting a specific device.

Comment: I succesfully selected my camera (nikon d3000), I can take a picture with it, but now I would like to have an preview of this picture... I have no code, because I did not find a way to get this picture...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExecuteCommand returns a WIA.Item which provide a Transfer method :

```
WIA.CommonDialog dialog = new WIA.CommonDialog();
WIA.Device camera = dialog.ShowSelectDevice(WIA.WiaDeviceType.CameraDeviceType, false, true);
WIA.Item takenItem = camera.ExecuteCommand("{AF933CAC-ACAD-11D2-A093-00C04F72DC3C}");

foreach (string formatId in takenItem.Formats)
{
    if (Guid.Parse(formatId) == System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid)
    {
        WIA.ImageFile wiaImage = takenItem.Transfer(formatId);

        var imageData = new MemoryStream( wiaImage.FileData.get_BinaryData());
        var image = Image.FromStream(imageData);
        //pictureBox1.Image = image;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I run this I get: System.NullReferenceException was unhandled Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: if `takenItem` is null then maybe you selected wrong device or your device doesn't support this command. you can check your device's supported commands through `camera.Commands`. otherwise call `Transfer` without any `formatId`

Comment: camera.Comands returnet only 2 commands: Synchronize and TakePicture. I tryed to call Transfer(), but the error remain the same.

Comment: I will accept your answer, and I will let you know if your code work on some other photo camera... it seems that my camera doesn't support this :(